# How to link (google-maps) infowindow text string?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, text, hyperlink, infowindow

I am having trouble finding a way to hyperlink the text in my infowindow. I have tried the window.location.href command but I don't want to link the marker itself as I need the text to be linked. I have spend a good hour googling but haven't found a way of doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) my code is below. The text that appears in the infowindows are in the contentstring variables.

Thankyou,
Anthony

```
function allbrisbaneparks() {
  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.51561168,153.0593704);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.59129579,153.0463111);
  var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.45968511, 153.0505714);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng1
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString1 = 'Mott Park'
  var contentString2 = 'Bushy Park'
  var contentString3 = "Catalina Park"

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    });

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng1,
      map: map,
      title: 'Mott Park'
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng2,
      map: map,
      title: 'Bushy Park'
  });
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng3,
      map: map,
      title: 'Catalina Park'
  });
  function addmarker(identity, content){
        google.maps.event.addListener(identity, 'click', function allbrisbaneparks() {
        infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent(content);//update the content for this marker
        infowindow.open(map, identity);

 });
}
addmarker(marker1, contentString1)
addmarker(marker2, contentString2)
addmarker(marker3, contentString3)
}
function domlistenerbrisbane(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', allbrisbaneparks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your contentStrings to:

```
var contentString = '<a href="your URL" >The address name</a>';
```